# C++ Array Error

Tags: c++, arrays

I created a random, and its size is created randomly. Then I assign random values to this array. Finally, I want to write odd values and even values into different arrays. But the last two `for` loops display wrong values for evenArray and oddArray.

Where is the error? Please help me identify the error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(time(0));
    int arraySize = rand() % 10 + 4;
    cout << "Array Size :  " << arraySize <<  endl;
    int myArray[arraySize];
    int oddIndex = 0;
    int evenIndex = 0;
    int oddArray[oddIndex];
    int evenArray[evenIndex];

    for( int m = 0 ; m < arraySize ; m++)
    {
        myArray[m] = rand() % 100 + 90 ;
        cout << m << "th value is : " << myArray[m] << endl;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < arraySize ; i++)
    {
        if( myArray[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            evenArray[evenIndex] = myArray[i];
            cout << "EVEN ARRAY " << evenIndex << "th element is " << evenArray[evenIndex] << endl;
            evenIndex++;
        }
        else
        {
            oddArray[oddIndex] = myArray[i];
            cout << "ODD ARRAY " << oddIndex << "th element is " << oddArray[oddIndex] << endl;
            oddIndex++;
        }
    }
    cout << "The total number of even array elements  : " << evenIndex  << endl;
    cout << "The total number of odd array elements  : " << oddIndex  << endl;

    cout <<  "/////////////////////////////////////////\n";
    cout << "EVEN VALUES" << endl;
    for( int i = 0 ; i < evenIndex ; i++ )
    {
        cout << i << "th even value is: " << evenArray[i] << endl;

    }
    cout <<  "/////////////////////////////////////////\n";
    cout << "ODD VALUES" << endl;
    for( int p = 0 ; p < oddIndex ; p++ )
    {
        cout << p << "th odd value is : " << oddArray[p] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because as it stands you are creating zero sized arrays for `oddArray` and `evenArray`

Comment: If this code actually compiles, it's only because you are using a non-standard C++ extension. The size of an array *MUST* be a compile-time constant. i.e. `const int oddIndex = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

```
int oddIndex = 0;
int evenIndex = 0;
int oddArray[oddIndex];
int evenArray[evenIndex];
```

As you can see you are initializing `oddArray` and `evenArray` with `0` size.What you can do is declare both arrays of size `arraySize`,or better you can use vectors

Answer (score 0):

You use wrong initialization of arrays length

```
int oddArray[oddIndex];
int evenArray[evenIndex];
```

In this lines you create two arrays of zero length. Further use to these arrays will lead to undefined behaviors.
If you need an array with dynamically changing length you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are rigth. I understand you.